# awk/sed help - how do I find columns that contain a comma and then double-quote them?

Tags: regex, perl, unix, awk, sed

I've searched the archives but cannot find this particular question and am having trouble piecing together awk parts to come up with an answer.  I have a Unix file with about a dozen columns delimited by pipes. I would like to take this delimited file, convert it to .csv and automate mailing it to staff to open in Excel.  My problem is that some of the columns have commas inside them (Ex: |RYAN, NOLAN| which makes conversion to .csv problematic.

Does anyone know a way in awk/sed/perl that will find the columns in which a comma exists (there could be multiple instances within a single row) and enclose each of those columns with double-quotes, which will allow Excel to properly open just a single column?

Ex dataset:

```
MSH|^~\&|IMT7||EXSCH|384^SCH|20150202082830||MFN^M02|RYAN, NOLAN|P|2.2|Last|First|DOE, JOHN|...
```

I would like the above to become:

```
MSH|^~\&|IMT7||EXSCH|384^SCH|20150202082830||MFN^M02|"RYAN, NOLAN"|P|2.2|Last|First|"DOE, JOHN"|...
```

Thank you gurus in advance!
Dave

Comment: can we assume that there is no `|` in content or there are maybe escaped or we should take internal pipe into account and in this case or are they presented ?

Comment: I'm not sure you really need to do anything. If you open such a file in Excel and say it's delimited, checking the "other" option in the list of possible delimiters and setting the value to the | character, it shouldn't matter that there are commas.

Answer (score 3):

**Using awk**

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if($i~/,/){$i="\""$i"\""}};print}' file
```

example

```
echo "MSH|^~\&|IMT7||EXSCH|384^SCH|20150202082830||MFN^M02|RYAN, NOLAN|P|2.2|Last|First|DOE, JOHN|..."|awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if($i~/,/){$i="\""$i"\""}};print}'
```

results

```
MSH|^~\&|IMT7||EXSCH|384^SCH|20150202082830||MFN^M02|"RYAN, NOLAN"|P|2.2|Last|First|"DOE, JOHN"|...
```

**using a sed approach**

```
sed  's/|\([^|]\+,[^|]\+\)|/|"\1"|/g' file
```

Comment: Use `-r` in `sed` so you do not need to escape all the `()`

Comment: Thank you Xorg!!  FYI, the awk works but the sed looks like has one misprint, places the quote outside the 2nd '|' :  |915|5557683||"DOE, JOHN|"|2014-01-13|

Comment: Answer edited to fix a small change....the sed command should work as expected now

Answer (score 2):

The following Perl script will do it, just save the script, and then pipe the file into it:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @out;
    foreach (split /\|/, $line) {
        $_ = qq("$_") if (/,/);
        push @out, $_;
    }
    print join "|", @out, "\n";
}
```

You could probably make this into a single line of Perl, but it's much easier to read this way.

Comment: Thanks Toby (just would prefer one liner for my bad memory...).

Answer (score 0):

With **sed**:

```
sed 's/\([^,|]*,[^,|]*\)/"&"/g' File
```

or

```
sed -r 's/([^,|]*,[^,|]*)/"&"/g' File
```

Surround every pattern matching the criteria (`sequence of non-, & non-| characters followed by , followed by sequence of non-, & non-| characters`) with `"`.

Comment: A.M.D., the sed -r is a thing of beauty, thank you for that as well as the explanation!

Comment: There is no need for the parens as you are already using `&`. Also following the `,` any character other than a `|` is permissible.